# In T-SQL is it possible to have a result set returned by a select with subselects that cannot be obtained using joins instead?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

**Given a SQL `SELECT` expression with arbitrarily nested subselect's, it always possible to rewrite said SQL expression so that it contains no subselect's and returns the same result set?**

**If so, is there an algorithm for doing so?**

**If not, is there a characterization of those `SELECT` expressions that cannot be rewritten?**

I'm making an application that will generate SQL `SELECT` statements.  I'm still designing how it will work at this point.  Here's the general idea, though:

The user will select what columns are displayed, how the results are sorted and how they are restricted.

The columns will not just be SQL columns but named objects such that the object can contain a SQL expression with column variables from multiple tables.  These objects will contain information on how to join to each other.

I want to make the configuration of these expressions to be as flexible as possible; if it's possible to write the SELECT statement that returns some result set `S`, then I'd like the application to be able to generate a `SELECT` statement that returns `S`.  One thing that's possible in SQL are sub-selects.  I've read that rewriting said sub-select's with JOINS is better performance wise.  Therefore I am considering disallowing sub-select's in the configuration.  However I do not want to do this unless every sub-select can be rewritten as a join.

Comment: The query optimizer will unwind, regroup and reorder whatever it can, and it can a lot. It's arguably possible to write code that will do the same better than the optimizer, but you're going to have a really hard time doing it.

Comment: I'm not trying to take the place of the optimizer.  If I could make it so that the configurer of my application does not have the option to do sub selects, then my coding and design will be much easier.  I do not want that restriction, though, if that limits the result sets that can be obtained.  I don't care what the optimizer does ha.

Comment: In my experience, is not always posible to do this, at my job i have to write querys to get a lot of reports and i always try to use every card under my sleeve to avoid subquerys in the columns (sometimes i use them in the FROM part) but sometimes it just can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

Subselects in the WHERE clause can often be impossible to rewrite as JOIN, especially if aggregate functions are in use.

Quoted from [here](http://www.programmershelp.co.uk/mysqlsubquery.php):

> Here is an example of a common-form subquery comparison which you can't do with a join: find all the values in table t1 which are equal to a maximum value in table t2.
>
> SELECT column1 FROM t1
>   WHERE column1 = (SELECT MAX(column2) FROM t2);
>
> Here is another example, which again is impossible with a join because it involves aggregating for one of the tables: find all rows in table t1 which contain a value which occurs twice.
>
> SELECT * FROM t1
>   WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(column1) FROM t1);

Therefore, if a complex subselect in the SELECT clause itself has subselects in its WHERE clause, that could be impossible to express as a JOIN.

```
SELECT T2.B, (SELECT A from t1 where t1.ID=T2.ID 
                         and 2=(SELECT COUNT(A) from t1 as TX WHERE TX.A=T1.A))
FROM T2
```

Comment: What about if it's in the column list, only?

Comment: Can the HAVING clause not do this?